# Data Set of all registered Defined-Benefit Pension schemes in the UK

Tags: data-request

Just a data set I'm trying to find.

Ideally with Company & Pension Assets data as well.

Help and ideas much appreciated.

---

The data exists (privately) in at least one place: The Pensions Regulator, as "The Official Register of Pension Schemes".

Extensive search suggests that it doesn't exist anywhere else, but I thought I'd ask the community anyway.

Comment: Have you ruled out scraping the page/source, or are you saving that as a last resort?

Comment: @BarryCarter I should've been clearer. The register isn't publicly available or displayed.

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment)

I didn't look too deeply, but it appears that someone (perhaps you) has requested this information before: https://data.gov.uk/data-request/directory-pension-fundspension-schemes-uk

The given link is broken, but https://eiopa.europa.eu/regulation-supervision/pensions/database-of-pension-plans-and-products-in-the-eea may be helpful, even though the UK is no longer a member of the EU.

Finally, http://www.thepensionsregulator.gov.uk/foi/lists-and-registers.aspx and http://www.thepensionsregulator.gov.uk/en/employers/duties-checker/outcomes/i-am-an-employer-who-has-to-provide-a-pension/choose-a-pension-scheme-or-check-your-existing-one.aspx may or may not be helpful, or you could try emailing them a request?

Comment: The UK is still a member of the EU, so that approach should keep working for the next couple of  years at least...

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Brexit was the vote to leave the EU, but the implementation phase hasn't occurred yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what I was after, and not in a particularly easy format, but this book, ["Pension Funds and their Advisers 2016"](http://www.wlrstore.com/apinfo/pension-fund.aspx) has proved to be a useful place to start.

(ISBN: 978-1-85783-234-1)